# How to change amount of categories listed on dashboard?

Tags: categories

I have 100+ categories & sub-categories for a site I'm working on.
How can i change the amount displayed in the list of categories (default 20 per page) on the dashboard?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set this using the Screen Options tab at the top of the category edit screen:

[image]

Comment: Sure! Screen Options is a sneaky little guy. Please accept this  answer with the check mark if it solved your issue, and welcome to WPSE!